# Codeigniter not accepting sql in allowed_filetypes for upload despite mime fix

Tags: sql, codeigniter, file-upload, file-type

Codeigniter (latest version) keeps spitting out "The filetype you are attempting to upload is not allowed" when trying to use 'sql' as the allowed filetype in `$config['allowed_types']`.

I've added `'sql' => 'text/x-sql'` to mimes.php config file and verified the browser is indeed recognizing the sql file as being of type `text/x-sql` but still, no luck.

Is there anything else I can check to get this working? I'd rather not use * for allowed file types if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this sounds really crazy but I would make the rule to accept anything (*) and I would check for extension (in this case *.sql). Reason why is simple, browser sets mimetype and I can not rely on that...

But please try following mimetypes `application/octet-stream` and of course `text/plain`.

You can check mimetype with `$_FILES['userfile']['type']`

Comment: *very* strangely, adding 'text/plain' to the 'sql' index in the mimes array did the trick. I say strangely because the browser is clearly posting the type as 'text/x-sql'.. so why CI matches 'text/plain' is a complete mystery to me. In any case, it works so thanks for the tip!

Comment: Yes browser looks at extension and sees that it is SQL therefore when you echo it out you see `text/x-sql`, but sql file is nothing more than text. CI and mimetypes is really mystery, I had troubles with *.xls files.